# Why touchmove is not considered as interaction with the document in this case?

Tags: javascript

I have this code for starting a video on mobile.

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', startVideo);

function startVideo() {
            const video = document.querySelector('.video');
            if(video.currentTime === 0 || video.paused) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    video.play()},100);
            }
        }
```

It gives me error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user
>   didn't interact with the document first.

But If I change touchmove to touchstart it works as it should - video starts playing on tap.
Why? And is there a way to fix it so it would work with touchmove?

Comment: I guess `touchmove` is considered meta, it's the user scrolling through the page, not interacting directly with it. The question I have is why you want `touchmove` if it works with `touchstart`? Or why not simply handle both events?

Comment: You are **only** replacing `touchmove` with `touchstart` right?  You still have the `setTimeout` in both examples?  Because I believe Barmar is likely correct.  The issue should be that you are trying to call `play` out of an indirect user interaction through `setTimeout`.

Comment: @ChrisG I have video as background in the first section of my website. It just seems more logical for me to start playing it when user starts to scroll down rather than playing it on tap.

Comment: @Allan I'm guessing the main issue here is that your desired behavior is precisely the one the browser is trying to prevent.

Comment: @Chris G Yeah it is probably the case

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with `touchmove`.

The reason is that you're calling `video.play()` in the `setTimeout()` callback. So when the call happens, the event listener has already returned.

You need to call it within the event listener function directly, not asynchronously.

```
function startVideo() {
    const video = document.querySelector('.video');
    if(video.currentTime === 0 || video.paused) {
        video.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it - gives me the same error. But works if I tap on the screen and then move.

Comment: @Allan : do you still have this issue ? found a solution ? let me know please

Comment: @M.Gara it seems that touchmove is not considered as interaction with the document. So I think I ended up showing image instead of video if video didn't start playing on autoplay.